# How to get values from Bootstrap modal form for use in MVC controller

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, asp.net-mvc-5

Before saving the data input into my Create and Edit views I'd like to open a Bootstrap modal form to get the user to enter their username and password again to confirm the data being submitted as well as selecting the reason for the data input from a drop-down list. I've set up the modal div with the three input fields 'username', 'password' and 'reason', but not sure of how to go about the processing from there. When the Save button on the modal is clicked I need to return to the controller and retrieve not only the values entered into the modal form but also those entered into the Create/Edit form in the view under the modal. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple, actually.

#### 1. Trap the form submit action and display modal dialog

```
$("form").on("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Show your modal
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
});
```

#### 2. On modal close, parse values and submit form

This should help:

```
// This handled the modal close event.
$("#myModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {

    // Remove the submit function from the form.
    $("form").off("submit");

    // Retrieve value from your input by id
    var firstValue = $("#InputId").val();

    // Retrieve value from your input by name
    var secondValue = $("input[name=InputName]").val();

    // Attach new value to the form
    $("<input type='hidden' name='firt-input' value='" + firstValue + "' />")
        .appendTo($("form"));

    // Attach other value to the form
    $("<input type='hidden' name='second-input' value='" + secondValue + "' />")
        .appendTo($("form"));

    // Finally, submit the form.
    // I'd rather use ajax here, but to make things simple, just submit your form.
    $("form").submit();

});
```

#### 3. Change your action

You can either create a new model, create a Wrapper model or just get the extra parameters, like:

```
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model, string username, string password)
{
   // Validate user/pass
}
```

Another option is to create a wrapper model, like:

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Model { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index(Wrapper<MyModel> model)
{
    // Validate user/pass
}
```

Comment: Can we have first name and last name as part of the Actual Model, and pass the entire Model to the MODAL, and access it there?

Comment: I mean the way we pass model to partial views, can we pass it to the MODAL also?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this code using VS2013 with a new Asp.Net MVC application.  This is doable using a `CustomViewModel` class that will have two properties.

**Step 1**
Create a CustomViewModel class

```
 public class PersonViewModel
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }        
    }
    public class CustomViewModel
    {
        public PersonViewModel Person { get; set; }
        public LoginViewModel LoginInfo { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using PersonViewModel to collect the Person information in the Create Form.  The CustomViewModel contains LoginInfo which is nothing but LoginViewModel class which is there in the AccountViewModels.cs class.

**Step 2**
Create a Create method and Create Method with HttpPost attribute that accepts CustomViewModel.

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(CustomViewModel viewModel)
        {

            return View("Index");
        }
```

**Step 3**
Create a `Create.cshtml` view and make it strongly typed to `@model CustomViewModel`.  Put loginViewModel stuff into a modal dialog div and the additional form view into another and everything into `@Html.BeginForm()`.

```
@model ModalDialogTest.Models.CustomViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>CustomViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Person.FirstName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Person.FirstName)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Person.LastName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Person.LastName)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @*Triggers Modal Dialog*@
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                Launch demo modal
            </button>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LoginInfo.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LoginInfo.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LoginInfo.UserName)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LoginInfo.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.LoginInfo.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.LoginInfo.Password)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                            @*Finally submits information to the Controller*@
                            <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-default" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

After you hit the Save Changes button on the Modal Dialog you can do additional logic into your Controller. There are additional things you will have to take care off like how you will handle small issues like validation and if you are doing it on multiple views than logic might change slightly.

Comment: Thanks for the help. If you tested it can I ask if you went as far as checking if the username and password was valid? I tried using the same code which processes the login form: var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password); if (user != null) ... but it throws an 'object reference not set to an instance of an object' exception. Any ideas?

Comment: Even when I change the check on identity the same error occurs as soon as I try to continue processing - the form doesn't appear to have populated the model at all